# lateinit property mMap has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I wrote these lines of code and got error

**Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mMap has not been initialized**

My method :

```
fun initCameraIdleListener() {
    var latitude = mMap.cameraPosition.target.latitude
    var longitude = mMap.cameraPosition.target.longitude
    myLatLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLatLng, 18f))

}
```

Comment: this is because your `mMap` is not initialized. make check for `mMap`, if it is initialized. like this :     `if (::mMap.isInitialized) `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the onMapReady callback you need to assign your propety to the argument received:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap
   initCameraIdleListener()
}
```

only after this you can call `initCameraIdleListener()`

Comment: I do this and it works fine on my phone. But Google Play automated tests still crash on Nokia 1 (which has Android Go). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown when you declare a property as `lateinit` and don't initialize it before using it.

```
class YourClass {

    // You're declaring you'll assign a value for this field later in the code
    lateinit var someObject : SomeType

    fun doSomething(){
        someObject.method() // Boom ! UninitializedPropertyAccessException
    }
}

class YourClass {

    // You're declaring you'll assign a value for this field later in the code
    lateinit var someObject : SomeType

    fun doSomething(){
        someObject = SomeObject()
        someObject.method() // Totally fine !
    }
}
```

To avoid this error, you MUST initalize your property before trying to access it, else you'll always get this error.

If initializing it depends on a condition and you're not sure it happened or not, you can check by calling `::propertyName.isInitialized` as [@kartik malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7870619/kartik-malik) suggested, before trying to use the property.